# Remove www from domain and force removal of extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have some rules that currently strip off the filename extension for my website and additionally a rule that will remove the www part. However if I were to visit `www.mydomain.co.uk/work` it will then load `www.mydomain.co.uk/work.php`

**My htaccess:**

```
# strips the www from URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI}/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Test this in Chrome dev tool and see what redirects are you getting in `Net` tab.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know you could do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the first specific to your domain and it won't have that problem. And you are using `REQUEST_URI` and the captured URI both at the same time in the rewrite rule. Try the rule this way.

```
# strips the www from URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.yoursite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```